Callback message printing not working as intended with retry logic
I am trying to make a program that does the following:

Processes a list of items.
Each item is processed by a dedicated function.
Each function call is wrapped in a with_retries block function.
Display messages are supposed to be displayed using callbacks.

I have successfully implemented callbacks, error handling, and retry logic, but there is something wrong in my implementation, because combining callbacks with retry logic breaks error handling.
This program:
def print_attempt_number(proc_id:, &callback)
    random = [true, false].sample
    if random
        message = "Attempt for ID: #{proc_id}"
        callback.call(proc_id, message) if callback
        # puts "PUTS: #{message}"
    else
        raise StandardError, "This is my error message"
    end
end

def handle_error(proc_id:, retries:, max_retries:, &callback)
    retries += 1
    retry_msg = "Retry #{retries} / #{max_retries}"
    # puts "PUTS: #{retry_msg}"
    callback.call(proc_id, retry_msg)
    return retries
end

def with_retries(max_retries:, proc_id:, &callback)
    retries = 0
    begin
        yield
    rescue StandardError => e
        retries = handle_error(proc_id: proc_id, retries: retries, max_retries: max_retries, &callback)
        sleep 1.0
        retry if retries < max_retries
    end
end

def process_item(proc_id:, &callback)
    init_msg = "Starting with #{proc_id}"
    callback.call(proc_id, init_msg)
    with_retries(max_retries: 3, proc_id:) do
        print_attempt_number(proc_id: proc_id, &callback)
    end
end



callback = Proc.new do |proc_id, message|
    puts "CALLBACK: #{proc_id}\t#{message}"
end

for id in 1..5 do
    process_item(proc_id: id, &callback)
    sleep 1.0
end

Produces this result:
CALLBACK: 1     Starting with 1
CALLBACK: 1     Attempt for ID: 1
CALLBACK: 2     Starting with 2
CALLBACK: 2     Attempt for ID: 2
callback_test.rb:8:in `print_attempt_number': This is my error message (StandardError)
        from callback_test.rb:38:in `block in process_item'
        from callback_test.rb:16:in `handle_error'
        from callback_test.rb:25:in `rescue in with_retries'
        from callback_test.rb:22:in `with_retries'
        from callback_test.rb:37:in `process_item'
        from callback_test.rb:49:in `block in <main>'
        from callback_test.rb:48:in `each'
        from callback_test.rb:48:in `<main>'
callback_test.rb:8:in `print_attempt_number': This is my error message (StandardError)
        from callback_test.rb:38:in `block in process_item'
        from callback_test.rb:23:in `with_retries'
        from callback_test.rb:37:in `process_item'
        from callback_test.rb:49:in `block in <main>'
        from callback_test.rb:48:in `each'
        from callback_test.rb:48:in `<main>'

However, switching from callback directly to puts produces the results as expected:
def print_attempt_number(proc_id:, &callback)
    random = [true, false].sample
    if random
        message = "Attempt for ID: #{proc_id}"
        # callback.call(proc_id, message) if callback
        puts "PUTS: #{message}"
    else
        raise StandardError, "This is my error message"
    end
end

def handle_error(proc_id:, retries:, max_retries:, &callback)
    retries += 1
    retry_msg = "Retry #{retries} / #{max_retries}"
    puts "PUTS: #{retry_msg}"
    # callback.call(proc_id, retry_msg)
    return retries
end

def with_retries(max_retries:, proc_id:, &callback)
    retries = 0
    begin
        yield
    rescue StandardError => e
        retries = handle_error(proc_id: proc_id, retries: retries, max_retries: max_retries, &callback)
        sleep 1.0
        retry if retries < max_retries
    end
end


def process_item(proc_id:, &callback)
    init_msg = "Starting with #{proc_id}"
    callback.call(proc_id, init_msg)
    with_retries(max_retries: 3, proc_id:) do
        print_attempt_number(proc_id: proc_id, &callback)
    end
end



callback = Proc.new do |proc_id, message|
    puts "CALLBACK: #{proc_id}\t#{message}"
end

for id in 1..5 do
    process_item(proc_id: id, &callback)
    sleep 1.0
end

Which produces:
CALLBACK: 1     Starting with 1
PUTS: Attempt for ID: 1
CALLBACK: 2     Starting with 2
PUTS: Retry 1 / 3
PUTS: Attempt for ID: 2
CALLBACK: 3     Starting with 3
PUTS: Retry 1 / 3
PUTS: Attempt for ID: 3
CALLBACK: 4     Starting with 4
PUTS: Retry 1 / 3
PUTS: Retry 2 / 3
PUTS: Retry 3 / 3
CALLBACK: 5     Starting with 5
PUTS: Attempt for ID: 5

I don't understand why that happens; how can I achieve the desired printing using callback for print messages?

Apparently, not passing it as a block (without the &) solved it for my use case:
def print_attempt_number(proc_id, callback)
    random = [true, false].sample
    if random
        message = "Attempt for ID: #{proc_id}"
        callback.call(proc_id, message)  # Use callback without block syntax
    else
        raise StandardError, "This is my error message"
    end
end

def handle_error(proc_id, retries, max_retries, callback)
    retries += 1
    retry_msg = "Retry #{retries} / #{max_retries}"
    callback.call(proc_id, retry_msg)  # Use callback without block syntax
    retries
end

def with_retries(max_retries, proc_id, callback)
    retries = 0
    begin
        yield  # Execute the block provided to with_retries
    rescue StandardError => e
        retries = handle_error(proc_id, retries, max_retries, callback)
        sleep 1.0
        retry if retries < max_retries
    end
end

def process_item(proc_id, callback)
    init_msg = "Starting with #{proc_id}"
    callback.call(proc_id, init_msg)  # Call the callback with init message
    with_retries(3, proc_id, callback) do
        print_attempt_number(proc_id, callback)  # Pass callback without using & syntax
    end
end

callback = Proc.new do |proc_id, message|
    puts "CALLBACK: #{proc_id}\t#{message}"
end

for id in 1..5 do
    process_item(id, callback)
    sleep 1.0
end


That's because you were originally passing the with_retries block to the with_retries method  in the callback variable. You thought you were calling your printing Proc inside with_retries, where you were in fact just calling the same block that yield was calling. This was basically randomly raising an exception inside your rescue block. Very difficult bug to figure out.

@Casper oh, that has been bugging me. Thank you for the explanation!
